# intrinsically matched Schottky diodes (sharing common substrate)?

Tags: schottky

I'm looking for a pair of Schottky diodes on a single die: one to use as a non-linear element and one to measure the temperature.  All of the dual Schottky's I've found so far are on separate dice, bonded in a single package.  (I presume this is to provide better isolation between the two.)

I know I can get dual NPN transistors and use them in a diode configuration, but I need the low Vf of a Schottky.

Is there a family of devices -- perhaps not Schottkys -- that would serve the same purpose?

Comment: Are not BAT54 etc. duals typically on a common substrate? [This](http://www.vishay.com/marcom/hn/announcements/vhn_po1110_0306.pdf) ad would imply so.

Comment: Have you considered the BAR42/BAR43: https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/bar42.pdf ? It is unclear if these are on the same die, they could be on the same leadframe and that would make them better thermally matched.

Comment: The BAT1705 may not be on the same substrate, but they should be cemented to the same leadframe base.

Comment: Commenters have pointed out that for temperature measurements, the diodes don't have to match; it's sufficient for them to share the leadframe.  Does someone want to make an answer of that so I can assign points?